# How to show the clicked category related posts on category detail page?

Tags: categories, pods-framework

I have used a custom page using this code, these links redirect to Category detail page which showing "Nothing Found". How can I show the clicked category related posts on category detail page? Note: I am using twentytwenty-child theme.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Our Jobs */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php wp_list_categories(array(
    'parent'        =>  '17',
    'show_option_all'    => '0',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => '',
    'feed_type'          => '',
    'feed_image'         => '',
    'exclude'            => '',
    'exclude_tree'       => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 0,
   'title_li'           => __( '<h2>' . __( 'heading' ) . '</h2>' ),
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'No categories' ),
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'walker'             => null
)); ?>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the category indeed have post(s), then the archive page would list the posts in that category, and your code is just fine, so this is probably a plugin issue - have you tried deactivating plugins? Or maybe your child theme have a `pre_get_posts` or similar filter which hides the category posts?

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you for answer, I will try this or may be I need to change some wp theme

Comment: @SallyCJ I have installed only one plugin (Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields) for custom post type. After uninstalled it, clicked category related posts are not showing.

Comment: In that case, try switching to the default theme (or the parent Twenty Twenty theme) and visit the category archive page (`/category/job/accounts`) and if the page is good, then the problem is with *your child theme*, and if you can share the files, I can help you check the code.

Comment: https://designtlc.com/using-pods-create-simple-effective-custom-post-types/

Comment: What do you mean by posting that URL? And note that I can't help you with PODS templating stuff, so please consult the plugin support forums, documentations, guides, etc. for help in using the plugin.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you for help using helpful guidelines. Please ignore the above url and I didn't mention you in that comment. I just added it for me.

Comment: If that [URL/article](https://designtlc.com/using-pods-create-simple-effective-custom-post-types/) helped you in solving the issue, then you should post an answer and explain how the article helped and include other information relevant to your solution. (and remember to accept your answer)